# Javascript is not working for all items in array of rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a database field to be compared live with an input field here is my codes below. It works fine for the first form but not for all. Javascript is not looping. All the latter forms uses the answer of first form and works as it is the first form.

```html
<h1>Pages#home</h1>
<% @questions.each do |question|%>
  <div>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h1><%= question.equation %> =</h1>
        </td>
        <td>
          <h1><%= question.put_result %></h1>
        </td>

        <%= form_for(question) do |f| %>
          <td>
            <%= f.text_field :result, :id=>"result" %>
          </td>
          <td>
            <%= f.text_field :put_result,:oninput=>"check(this)" %>
          </td>

          <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
            function check(input) {
              if (input.value != document.getElementById('result').value) {
                input.setCustomValidity('incorrect');
              } else {
                // input is valid -- reset the error message
                input.setCustomValidity('');
              }
            }
          </script>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Firstly you're repeating the `id` of the `input` multiple times which is invalid - hence your main issue. Secondly you're repeating the `check()` function for each row of the table you loop through. Define the `check()` function once, outside of the loop.

Comment: but how. I am very poor in javascript